# How can I change a plugin's URL?

Tags: plugins, urls

I'm trying to use the OTW Portfolio Light plugin and what it does is adds it's own bit in the URL before the post type and I can't find where to change it.

Going to a profile page brings up the proper URL:
`site.com/portfolio-name`

But going to a portfolio item includes what I guess is the custom post name. So you get:
`site.com/otw-portfolio/portfolio-item`

I can't get the otw-portfolio out of, or changed, in the URL.

Support, as with most plugins it seems is near nonexistent so I'm looking around for help.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the slug, replace the line:

```
    'rewrite' => true,
```

at `otw-portfolio-light.php` inside `$args = (.....);` for `register_post_type( 'otw-portfolio', $args );` with:

```
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'new-slug'),
```

**note:**

- this will be overridden on plugin update
- additional you might have to go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and save to make changes appear

Comment: The way that's worded is a bit confusing. The only `'rewrite' => true,` is under the `function register_otw_portfolio_light` in that file.  

Are you saying put it inside the `$args = (.....);` tag replacing the ... ? Or straight replace the code with the one you provided? If I replace the rewrite with the one you provided I get an internal server error.

Comment: I guess it's the only line exactly like this. Sorry if the wording is confusing - not a native speaker. Just replace the line. I have a typo in my answer I correct it now.

Comment: Just noticed it too and changed it. Works like a charm thanks very much!